# Jquery Ajax how return Errors from PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have simple, form which works with Jquery Ajax, but I don't know how can I get my Errors from php.

My Form

```
<form action="customer.php" method="post" class="addForm">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"> <br>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name"> <br>
    <button type="submit" name="btnAdd">Add New Customer</button>
</form>
```

My Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("form.addForm").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // form's url and method
            var addForm_URL = $("form.addForm").attr("action");
            var addForm_Method = $("form.addForm").attr("method");

            var username_Val = $("input[name='username']").val();
            var name_Val = $("input[name='name']").val();

            var btnAdd_Val = $("button[name='btnAdd']").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: addForm_URL,
                method: addForm_Method,

                data: {
                    username_Post: username_Val,
                    name_Post: name_Val,
                    btnAdd_Post: btnAdd_Val
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("input[name='username']").val("");
                        $("input[name='name']").val("");
                    } else {
                        console.log(data); // here should be my errors
                    }

                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My php

```
if (isset($_POST['btnAdd_Post']) && empty($_POST['username_Post'])) {
//some stuff
    echo 'Error 1';
}

if (isset($_POST['btnAdd_Post']) && $_POST['name_Post'] == "my1") {
//some stuff
    echo 'Error 2';
}
if (isset($_POST['btnAdd_Post']) && !empty($_POST['name_Post'])) {
//some stuff
    echo 'Error 3';
}
```

As I use **e.preventDefault()**, I can't use any **exit()** or **headers** in my php.
How can I get my echo Error 1,2,3 from php put in my Ajax and priant some stuff or redirect ?

Thanks

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is Javascript and does not affect PHP

Comment: `$("button[name='btnAdd']").val()` That button doesn't have a value

Comment: "_// here should be my errors_" Not really. `data` in that `if` branch is empty, your errors/the response from your PHP script would be available inside the `if (data) {` branch.

Comment: You should return a proper JSON data structure. Then you can put your errors in there under a specific key, and on the frontend you check whether there is anything under that key or not.

Comment: my bad, still learning. In other examples I just add in my btn value="ok", but it works with value tag or without it.

Comment: "// here should be my errors", **data** in that **if** branch isn't **empty**. I do some insert stuff, so didn't posted all code. I just said "//some stuff". I get my **echo 'Error 1,2 or 3';** but with **console.log();** way.

Will see for **JSON data structure**.
Thanks

Comment: in that case u can just replace `if (data) { ` with `if (data.substr(0,5)!=='Error')` but you should think about returning json responses from php

Comment: Set appropriate HTTP code to indicate an error and implement the error() method in jquery to catch it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dont allow the post so the you cant get the $_POST info, so ether you have to let it go through with the post and catch the errors with php or log the errors with jQuery.

As far as I'm aware the you do the ajax call to prevent to reload the page and thus not accessing the PHP, but this means you'll have to catch the errors with jQuery as well.